# VueJS: Adding a class to one element if a class exists on another element

Tags: vue.js

I'm working in VueJS. I'm trying to bind a class to one element based on an existence of a class on another element. The below is in a :for loop to print out the list.

The `'#accordion-'+(index+1))` is the id of the div I want to check to see if a class exists on it.

I wrote a method and it works UNTIL I check the element's classList. Right now, I'm only doing a console log, but eventually this will return true and hopefully the class will apply.

```
methods: {
  existingTopic: function(lcDivID) {
    const element = document.querySelector(lcDivID);
    console.log(element); //It gives me the element.
    /* The below is where it crashes */
    console.log(element.classList.contains("collapsePanelExistingTopic"));
  }
}
```

I find it so frustrating. I've spent a day on this without any results. Any help you can provide it would be great.

Comment: When it crashes, what error do you see?

Comment: I get a "Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is, you can also use `this.$el` as `document`

```
...
methods: {
    hasClass() {
      const element = this.$el.querySelector('h1')
      if (element.classList.contains('your-class-here')) {
        console.log(true)
        this.$el.querySelector('anotherelement').classList.add("your-another-class");
      } else {
        console.log(false)
    }
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.hasClass()
}
...
```

**Alternative**

```
<h1 class="mb-5 fs-lg" ref="myElement">Sign up</h1>
...
methods: {
  hasClass() {
    const element = this.$refs.myElement
    if (element.classList.contains('mb-5')) {
      console.log(true)
      this.$el.querySelector('anotherelement').classList.add("your-another-class");
    } else {
      console.log(false)
    }
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.hasClass()
}
...
```

So you can define `ref` as `:ref="index+1"` in your loop

Comment: OK. I'm going to give this a shot. Thank you,,,I'll get back to you :-)

Comment: I apologize. I have a really stupid question. How would I call up hasClass()? Can I use this on a v-bind:class on another element? This is my "existingTopic" in use below.

 <div id="timeList" class="timeListDiv" :id="'tTimeDiv'+(index+1)" v-bind:class="{ieTimeList: existingTopic('#accordion-'+(index+1))}">

would I do...
 <div id="timeList" class="timeListDiv" :id="'tTimeDiv'+(index+1)" v-bind:class="{ieTimeList: hasClass()}">

Comment: Hmmm... it's not working.

I'm trying to bind a class on one element based on another having the class. 

Because it's dynamic, I have to check within it's own index. 

Thus I'm trying to call up the function on the div I want to set the class based on if it exists on another div with an id of #accordion- + the index number +1. Ugh.

<div id="timeList" class="timeListDiv" :id="'tTimeDiv'+(index+1)" v-bind:class="{ieTimeList: existingTopic('#accordion-'+(index+1))}">